# Making the 4th item in a row of icons look clickable?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, ux-designer

So im creating a dashboard for a device and I'm finding out that only 1 out of the 4 icons are clickable and will link to a new page. I thought about adding text underneath the icon that says "View More" underlined in blue, but I'm not sure that fits in with the rest of the design. Is there something I could do with the icon itself to let users know you can click on this? Here is the layout:

[image]

The 4th icon in question looks like this. (I added the blue details text, but am unsure if it fits with the rest of the icons which have text underneath, but no clickability)

[image]

Comment: What purpose do the other cards serve? Is there data being visualized?

Comment: @MikeM Yes standard data, such as online/offline status, battery life and signal strength

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend mixing clickable and non-clickable icons. Making the non-clickable icons look non-clickable could make them look temporarily disabled, or cause other confusion as to why they don't work.

The Usage icon looks like it might be more visually important than a decorative icon, so perhaps you could make it stand apart from the others through elevation (on its own card), size (more prominent than the others) or other visual separation. If it has to be the same size and proximity as the other icons, though, don't make any of them clickable and just keep doing what you're doing with the Details link, which is clearly clickable.